# blender 2.91 how to export vdb sequences

Tags: physics

on blender 2.91, mesh to volume: OK and good
But after?
Is it possible to export the vdb sequence?

Thanks,
daniel

Comment: You can also convert it back to a mesh but that's it, for now.